# How to find $P(N=3\mid X_4=1,X_5=2)$ where $X_i$'s are i.i.d $\text{Exp}(1)$ and $N=\min\{n\ge 1:X_n\in [1,2]\}$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

This is a rather simple exercise I stumbled upon:

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be i.i.d $\text{Exp}(1)$ random variables and $N=\min\{n\ge 1:X_n\in [1,2]\}$.

How can we find the conditional probability $P(N=3\mid X_4=1,X_5=2)$?

For every $n\ge 1$, I have $$P(N>n)=P(X_1\notin [1,2],X_2\notin [1,2],\ldots,X_n\notin [1,2])=(1-p)^n\,,$$  where $$p=P(X_1\in[1,2])=\frac1e-\frac1{e^2}$$

In other words $N$ has a geometric distribution with pmf $$P(N=n)=p(1-p)^{n-1}\mathbf1_{n\in \{1,2,\ldots\}}$$

But how to argue regarding the value of the conditional probability? I am not sure how to express the event $\{N=3\}$ in terms of the $X_i$'s or the event $\{X_4=1,X_5=2\}$ in terms of $N$ so that I can work with either the distribution of $X_i$'s or $N$.

Does $\{N=3\}$ imply $\{X_1\notin [1,2],X_2\notin [1,2],X_3 \in [1,2]\}$? Any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does $\{N=3\}$ imply $\{X_1\notin [1,2],X_2\notin [1,2],X_3 \in [1,2]\}$?

Yes, that is correct.   Furthermore, it is an *equivalence*.   $N$ is the value of the index for the first sample from the series to occur in the interval.

$${~~~~N=\min\{n: n\geq 1, X_n\in[1..2]\}\\\Updownarrow\\~~~~ X_N\in[1..2]\wedge\forall k\in[\![1..N-1]\!]~.X_k\notin[1..2]}$$

So then, $\mathsf P(N=3)~{=\mathsf P(X_1\notin[1..2])\mathsf P(X_2\notin[1..2])\mathsf P(X_3\in[1..2])\\=(1+\mathrm e^{-2}-\mathrm e^{-1})^2\,(\mathrm e^{-1}-\mathrm e^{-2})}$

---

Now use  Bayes' Rule .$$\mathsf P(N=3\mid X_4=1, X_5=2)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(N=3)f_{X_4,X_5\mid N=3}(1,2)}{f_{X_4}(1)f_{X_5}(2)}$$.

And  $f_{X_4,X_5\mid N=3}(1,2)=f_{X_4,X_5\mid X_1\notin[1..2],X_2\notin[1..2],X_3\in[1..2]}(1,2) = ....$

Comment: Thanks, but can I not say $\{N=3\}=\{X_1\notin [1,2],X_2\notin [1,2],X_3 \in [1,2]\}$ is independent of  $\{X_4=1,X_5=2\}$?

Comment: Yes, you can say that. @StubbornAtom That is the very thing to do.